# wordpress post redirect rule not working IIS / coldfusion

Tags: wordpress, iis, url-rewriting, coldfusion

I'm trying to redirect wordpress posts to a coldfusion page by using an IIS URL redirect. the posts link is

```
domain.com/?p=345
```

so I have set up the following redirect using the rolling Pattern

```
/?p=([0-9]+)
```

To point to the following page...

```
/blog.cfm?ID={R:1}
```

But sadly when I check out the page, it simply refreshes and doesn't redirect to     the blog.cfm page.

Any help or advice much appreciated.

Below is the full web.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="wp post redirect" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/?p=([0-9]+)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="blog.cfm?ID={R:1}" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Can you please add to your question your redirect rule from web.config

Comment: Hi, I have now added the web.config. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule should be like that:

```
<rule name="wp post redirect" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^$" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=([0-9]+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="blog.cfm?ID={c:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
</rule>
```

**Explanation:**

Your rule had mistake `<match url=` contains only url path without query string.

`<match url="^$" />` that means apply this rule for requests, which valid for `^$` regexp. It is only for homepage

`<add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="p=([0-9]+)" />` that means apply this condition. Only if query string valid for `p=([0-9]+)` regexp

`<action type="Redirect" url="blog.cfm?ID={c:1}" appendQueryString="false" />` Redirect to `log.cfm?ID={c:1}` where `{c:1}` is first match from regexp from  condition

Comment: Many thanks Victor, this now works a treat. I'm now to IIS Url Rewrite, but the seem to be a very useful tool.